# passing optional values to protractor 'toEqual()' assertion

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm writing protractor test specs for my app, but there's a scenario where the value of my model can be dynamic.

Consider the following spec:

`expect(el.getText()).toEqual('one');`

the problem is that the value can either be `one` or `two`. Is there a way or any method that will allow me to pass multiple values in the `toEqual()` assertion.

I've tried passing `one || two` in the `toEqual()` assertion but it won't succeed since it considers it to be a complete string rather being a expression.

Any help appreciated.

**Note**  I wouldn't want to use `el.getText().then()` promise because I might have multiple elements in my view and I need to test them in a single spec `it` therefore using promise would result in nesting which wouldn't be pretty.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex with .toMatch()